# findcontrol does not find dynamically added control which was just addes one line before

Tags: asp.net, controls, findcontrol

who can explain this to me?

```
CheckBox ckRequest = new CheckBox();
ckRequest.ID = "ckRequest";
ckRequest.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.CkIsRequested_DataBinding);
container.Controls.Add(ckRequest);
Control con = container.FindControl("ckRequest");
```

Debugging shows that con is still null.

Debugging also shows me, that conteiner.Controls hase one Item with ID "ckRequest"

How can this be????

---

Many thanks for your answers.

Actually I try the following. 
[findcontrol does not find dynamically created control in rowUpdating eventhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874940/findcontrol-does-not-find-dynamically-created-control-in-rowupdating-eventhandle)
It makes sense to me, that findcontrol works only on the created page.

At which point in time the visual tree of the page is created?

Comment: provide more code? what is container?

Comment: what type is container? Is it a user control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FindControl` only works when the control is in the visual tree of the page

In your case you can try this

```
var checkBoxesInContainer = container.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx

Comment: System.Web.UI.Control container

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
Control con = 
    container.Controls.Cast<Control>().First(item => item.ID == "ckRequest");
```

Comment: System.Web.UI.Control container

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to following:

```
//GET THE CHECKBOXLIST
Control c = phCategories.Controls.Cast<Control>().First(item => item.ID == "cblCatID-" + catID && item.GetType().Name == "CheckBoxList");
if (c.GetType().Name == "CheckBoxList")
{
  cbl = (CheckBoxList)c;
}
```

For some reason I needed to cast this as a control first. If I did not do it this way, I seemed to grab a label instead (which didn't make sense to me, because it wasn't actually grabbing a label). Hope it helps somebody.